# App ownership in app store

Tags: ios, iphone

I am currently working on an iOS app that has developers working from different locations. Can ownership of the app be shared between more than one developer so that they have full control over the app?

Answer (score 1):

You should create an Apple Developer account as an *Organization* and can then add other developers to the team. An individual account is designed to be what the title states- for individuals.

Here is the link to Apple's developer membership page: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Answer (score 0):

If they have an account connected to your `itunesconnectaccount` then yes, you can set the management of that user as developer.

This can be done like so:

[image]

Then

[image]

You can select either all apps or just a particular app!

Hope this answers your question :)